# angularjs - evaluate Expression inside validator directive

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-validation

I have a custom validation attribute directive that can get expressions, for example:

```
<input type="text" uiSelectRequired="isParam == true"/>
```

how do I evaluate this expression in my directive assuming I cannot use isolated scope?

Thanks.

```
angular.module("app").directive('uiSelectRequired', function () {
        return {
            require: 'ngModel',
            link: function (scope, element, attr, ctrl) {
                ctrl.$validators.uiSelectRequired = function (modelValue, viewValue) {
                    var attrbs = attr;
                    var determineVal;
                    if (angular.isArray(modelValue)) {
                        determineVal = modelValue;
                    } else if (angular.isArray(viewValue)) {
                        determineVal = viewValue;
                    } else {
                        return false;
                    }
                    return determineVal.length > 0;
                };
            }
        };
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `attr.uiSelectRequired` to get the expression, and use [$scope.$eval()](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope#$eval) to evaluate it.

Note that your usage of the directive is wrong. It should be

```
<input type="text" ng-model="something" ui-select-required="isParam == true"/>
```

I'm also usure what you're trying to do with the angular.isArray() checks. Both the view value and the model value of an input of type text will be a string. Not an array.